# Pass array just what user selects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to pass data what user checked. My problem now.. it pass all..
This is my demo code and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nymnv)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of modules; let i = index;">
    <div class="col-md-1 align-center">{{i+1}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="modules[i].module_name" value="{{modules[i].module_name}}" disabled>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="radio" class="form-control" [checked]="modules[i].action.read" (change)="modules[i].action.read"  name="access_{{modules[i].company_id}}" id="package-1">
<label for="package-1">Read</label>
 </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="radio" [checked]="modules[i].action.write" (change)="modules[i].action.write" class="form-control" name="access_{{modules[i].company_id}}" id="package-2">
<label for="package-2">write</label>
 </div>
 <button (click)="test(item)">test</button>


</div>
```

**Component**

```
 test(val){
    console.log(val)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues mainly:

1. You need to create a unique id for both label and id attributes within the for-loop.
2. Next, create a method that will toggle the read/write property of each individual module. This ensures that if read is set then write will be false and vice versa.

.ts

```
toggleReadWrite(module: any, isRead: boolean) {
   if (isRead) {
     module.action.read = !module.action.read;
     module.action.write = false;
   } else {
     module.action.write = !module.action.write;
     module.action.read = false;
   }
}
```

.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of modules; let i = index;">
    <div class="col-md-1 align-center">{{i+1}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="modules[i].module_name" 
               value="{{modules[i].module_name}}" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" [checked]="modules[i].action.read"
            (change)="toggleReadWrite(modules[i], true)" 
            name="access_{{modules[i].company_id}}" id="package+1+{{i}}">
        <label for="package+1+{{i}}">Read</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="radio" [checked]="modules[i].action.write"
            (change)="toggleReadWrite(modules[i], false)" class="form-control"
            name="access_{{modules[i].company_id}}" id="package+2+{{i}}">
        <label for="package+2+{{i}}">write</label>
    </div>

    <button (click)="test(item)">test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a [working-stackblitz-for-the-same](https://angular-1rlbvw.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make the `id` of radio buttons unique as you are looping through it.

`id="package-1{{i}}"`

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control" [checked]="modules[i].action.read" (change)="modules[i].action.read"  name="access_{{modules[i].company_id}}" 
id="package-1{{i}}">

<label for="package-1{{i}}">Read</label>
```

Also, I am not sure what is your desired output, please explain more.